# How to identify the "client application" at the "resource server" in a OIDC/OAuth2 flow

Tags: oauth-2.0, authorization, openid-connect, websecurity

I have multiple client applications connecting to several different API services in a microservices setup. I use OIDC for User authentication and then OAuth2 Access tokens for client apps to authorize to API services (resource servers).

Many different apps can call the same APIs if they have the access token with the required scopes. Tha API server only checks if the claim is present in the access token to permit the call.

One of our API services (say, a ticket booking app) needs to know who the caller is to do some app specific validations and also to do some logging for invoicing etc.

How do we know who the caller is from just the Access Token `JWT`? While OIDC mentions `azp` as a means to tell who the authorized party was for the `Identity Token`, there isn't an equivalent defined for `Access Token`. Anybody has any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the token introspection endpoint defined by OAuth 2.0 ([OAuth 2.0 Token Introspection](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7662))

This endpoint is exposed to verify the token validity as well as to retrieve some information such as scopes, username of end user as well as importantly for your case the client ID of the client ([Introspection Response](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7662#section-2.2)).

Alternatively, check about access token JWT configuration of your authorization server. Since you get a JWT it might be possible to add client id to JWT which will avoid this extra introspection call.

Comment: Thank you. This kind of validates that there is no mandatory claim that shows the `clientid`. Even in `token introspection` endpoint, the `clientid` is optional as per the specs.

We are developing our own Authorization Server, based on a certified OpenID provider library and I think we should be able to add the `clientid` in the JWT itself.

Comment: Yes you should be able to add this parameter to the response. Specification only mandate the valid state. But it mention other possible parameters as I have highlighted. OAuth 2.0 is a framework which you can build your solutions on (ex:- OpenID Connect is such an extension) So take that flexibility when implementing. Only requirement is to follow the standard recommendations